# Cannot move_uploaded_file to /tmp

Tags: php, apache, permissions, move-uploaded-file

Here my code of `uploads.php`:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$uploads_dir = '/tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir . $name);
```

It returns `1` (aka `true`) but the file is not copied to `/tmp`.
If I set `$uploads_dir` to a different directory with permissions 777 it works.
If the target directory is wrong or does not have the right permissions I get an error message.

The `/tmp` directory as the correct permission I guess:

```
$ ls -l / | grep tmp
drwxrwxrwt  21 root root      20480 apr 21 17:39 tmp
```

so why it returns `true` but does not copy anything there?

Comment: You must specify the target file name as well `$uploads_dir = '/tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . 'filename';`. You are trying to replace the **directory** entry **/tmp** with the new file.

Comment: @JohnHanley sorry I don't understand. I contatenate `$upload_dir` with `$name`

Comment: You are specifying a directory name for the destination. You must specify a full path including the file name.

Answer (score 0):

If your tmp directory is in the same level of the file uploads.php change:

```php
$uploads_dir = '/tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

to this:

```php
$uploads_dir = __DIR__ . '/tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Or if the folder it's in the root level (aka **/** )
You need to descend to the same level like:

```php
$uploads_dir = __DIR__ . '/../../tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

I hope it's help you.

Comment: Sorry but `/tmp` is an absolute path. It's the default temporary directory in Linux. I don't want a path relative to the server directories.

Comment: And Why you moving from the temporary files directory, if the file already in the temporary directory? Print in the screen the two variables: $_FILES and you $uploads_dir

Comment: Because the initial temporary directory is under `/tmp/systemd-private-*` accessible only as `root`. The uploaded file should be accessible from other applications, but it's a temporary file so I don't need to move it to, say, my home folder.

Comment: So if /tmp is at a different level, try including it in open_basedir.